# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'configurations') from @react-native-community/cli-platform-ios

Tags: command-line-interface, react-native-community

i recently updated react-native to 0.69 and with it react-native-reanimated 2.8 not working so than i decided to install react-native 0.68.2 again but when starts react-native run-android it's getting error. now my all react-native projects with 0.68.2 showing same error. please guys help me out.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMKcj.png)

Comment: Have you been able to get an answer?

Answer (score 4):

// const configurations = userConfig.configurations || [];

let configurations="";

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: the above solution worked for me. the mentioned change should be in the file under: "node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/build/config/index.js" (was line 102 for me). notice you need to add a new line after the ";", before the "let"